# Does Magento support Oauth for customers?

Tags: magento2, oauth

I went through the documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html

But it's not clear to me whether I can use it for customer authentication.
I want customers to visit a site, say tool.example.com, which will NOT be a magento site, click a login button, get redirected to an Oauth screen at magento.example.com (which will be a magento site). I don't want the customers to enter their Magento account's credentials on the third party tool. Then I would like to fetch and display on tool.example.com some details like the list of orders placed by the user and the items currently in the user's cart.

If this is not supported out of the box, is there any extensions that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, Magento is not Oauth provider/service. It only allows for customer to connect into account through other providers